# My PHP file will not execute by cronjob

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, cron

I hope I'm posting in the right place, I thought I should go to the linux zone but it maybe be a code problem.

I have the following php script:

```
<?php


use function commands\createWalletsForMain;
use function commands\creditWallet;
use function commands\debitWallet;
use function commands\getConfig;
use function commands\selectAlts;
use function commands\selectMains;
use function commands\updateConfig;
use function commands\selectUncreditedTransactions;
use function commands\selectWallet;
use function commands\updateTransaction;


include_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once '../processors/commands.php';
include_once '../secret/esiConn.php';
include_once '../secret/dbconn.php';

$newConn = createConnection();
$mains = selectMains($newConn);
$uncreditedTransactions = selectUncreditedTransactions($newConn);

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
$log = new Logger('wallet');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler("../processors/logs/wallet.log"));


if($uncreditedTransactions->rowCount() != 0) {
    foreach ($uncreditedTransactions as $row) {
        if(selectWallet($newConn,$row['character_id']) != null) {

            creditWallet($newConn, $row['character_id'],$row['amount']);
            updateTransaction($newConn,$row['transactionID']);
            $log->warning($row['character_id']." credited with ".$row['amount']);
        }
        else
        {
            $log->warning("User has no wallet");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $log->warning("All transactions credited");
}

if(getConfig($newConn,'ProcessedMonth') == date("m") )
{
    foreach ($mains as $row)
    {
        $totalALTS = selectAlts($newConn,$row['main_id'])->rowCount();
        if(selectWallet($newConn,$row['main_id']) != null) {
            debitWallet($newConn, $row['main_id'], ($totalALTS + 1) * 50000000);
            $log->warning($row['main_id']." has been debited ".(($totalALTS + 1) * 50000000).' isk.');
        }
        else
        {
            $log->warning("User has no wallet");
        }
    }
    updateConfig($newConn,'ProcessedMonth',date('m', strtotime('+1 month')));
}

foreach ($mains as $row) {
    if(selectWallet($newConn,$row['main_id']) == null)
    {
        createWalletsForMain($newConn, $row['main_id']);
        $log->warning('Wallet has been created for '.$row['main_id']);
    }
}
closeConnection();
```

I added the file on my apache2 server and i added the following line in the crontab:

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/eve/processors/wallet.php
```

However it doesn't execute it, i've tried to manually run the code runing `php /var/www/eve/processors/wallet.php` in the console and this indeed triggers the script and it works.

I am a bit lost....i've tried to figure it out for 2 days....

Comment: I think cron would email you with error messages. Perhaps an environment problem

Comment: I've even checked the cron log and this is the only entry it gives:

`CRON[43414]: (crarsene) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/eve/processors/wallet.php)`

Comment: `*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/eve/processors/wallet.php > /tmp/wallet.txt 2>&` perhaps. See what is going on

Comment: I just tried with the `tmp/wallet.txt`.
It says it executed it `CRON[44172]: (crarsene) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/eve/processors/wallet.php > /tmp/wallet.txt 2>&)` but no wallet.txt file was created in /tmp

Comment: Has it executed - i.e. the file exists?

Comment: If it has perhaps confirm by adding code to the php file to log info

Comment: It should be `>&1`. Does /usr/bin/php exist.

Comment: I have a logged in the file that writes out, every time i manually call it with php it logs but with cron it does nothing, not even the /tmp/wallet.txt was created.

Comment: Yes,  `/usr/bin/php` exists.

Comment: No /tmp/wallet.txt. Get a shell script to execute your php script

Comment: It may be to do with your cli and php set up try `*/3 * * * * wget http://www.example.com/eve/processors/wallet.php` instead

Comment: Managed to solve the problem.... my code was actually the issue.

My `include_once` wore the cause as those paths should never be declared like that, now i've read about it. My bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem.... my code was actually the issue. My include_once wore the cause as those paths should never be declared like that, now i've read about it. My bad :)